# Nyquist stability of a dataset

Tags: python, stability, nyquist

I'm trying to find the stability of a dataset of (re, img) points I get from a circuit simulation in SPICE. In the end I would like to have a script that starting from a set of points gives you the stability of a system according to Nyquist criteria (how many times does the Nplot encircle the (-1, j0) point), phase margin, gain margin and module margin etc...

All I could find in the control python package section was how to determine the stability of a system if you have a detailed numerator denominator transfer function but nothing suitable if you a have a set of points.

I'm probably missing something like how to find zeros and poles when you have a dataset, how to interpolate transfer function with numerator and denominator starting from a dataset...

Thanks for your help,

cordially

Claudio